# PowerShell Regular Expression Match IP Not Proceeded and Not Followed by IP

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm attempting to use the match operator in PowerShell to find IP addresses that are not proceeded and not followed by an IP. My goal is to capture just IP's and NOT the IP's that are followed by subnet masks. Also, I used get content on a text file and then did a for each through it using the match at each line.

This is what I have so far and I don't appear to be getting the correct results:

```
(?<!\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?!\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

**Example data:**

10.0.0.1

word 11.11.11.11

word 12.12.12.12 255.255.255.0

15.15.15.15 255.255.255.0

**Expected Matches:**

10.0.0.1

11.11.11.11

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much. You should post as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Here's an answer someone else posted and then removed and was what I ended up using:  (?<!\.\d{1,3}\s+)\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}\b(?!\s*\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex isn't always the answer.

```
$IPs = $line.Split().Where({$_ -as [IPAddress]})
if ($IPs.Count -eq 1) {
    $match = $IPs[0]
}
```

### What this does

`$line` represents the current line.

First, split it into an array (the `.Split()` method splits on whitespace by default), then filter the array with `.Where()` to only include elements that can be succesfully cast to an `[IPAddress]`. That gives you an array of all the IP addresses in the line.

After that, test that the count is 1, so you only proceed when it found a single IP address.

Comment: Super elegant.  Does `.Split()` divide on whitespace by default?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 yes, added that to my explanation

Comment: This is quite a unique approach, thank you for this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew some people are insistent on wanting to solve a problem with regex specifically. You might as well post yours since you address why the regex wasn't working and what changes it would need in order to work. Both answers can be useful and it's up to the OP to accept what they want :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to simplify the task is to use chained operators:

```
$Lines = Get-Content $file
@($Lines) -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' -notmatch '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' -replace '.+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).+','$1'
```

Using the operators this way causes them to act as filters, so the `-match` operator will filter out all lines that don't contain an IP address at all, then the `-notmatch` will filter out the ones that also contain a following subnet mask, and finally the `-replace` operator will extract the IP address from the lines that passed both tests.

Comment: Also a very nice technique!

Comment: @briantist - thanks.  Your solution is nice, too.  This one still uses regex, but they're all rather straight-forward. Using chained comparison operators can be a very efficient way to filter string arrays, but I don't see it used very often.

Comment: I agree; there's often a feeling of "but I have to do it all in one regex" and it can be easy to forget: you have an entire programming language at your fingertips. Often a problem can be done better without regex, or even more commonly as you did: with a combination of both that can't be done in pure regex.

Comment: I had no idea, thank you for sharing this approach. Learning so much.